# Mirroring Radio selection based on value works then doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pairs of radio buttons. I want the second pair to match the selection of the first.

The system I am working in **DOES NOT ALLOW for the names and ids to be different**

I created the following code and it only seems to work one way or the other even though it is grabbing the correct values and I cannot figure out what the problem is. Can someone please tell me what is going on here?

If you select Yes at the start, it is mirrored. then select No it is mirrored, but when you go back from No to Yes it stops mirroring. The same is true if you start with No -> Yes -> No.

```js
function setAutoInitiateIRRadio(){

alert($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val());

    if($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
    $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="Yes"]').attr('checked',true);
    $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="No"]').attr('checked',false);   
    }
    else if($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val() == "No"){
    $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="No"]').attr('checked',true);
    $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="Yes"]').attr('checked',false);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
          <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label" for="radIssueReviewRequired">Issue Review Required?:</label>
          <div class="radio-list">
           <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radIssueReviewRequired" name="radIssueReviewRequired" alt="Select if an Issue Review is required." title="Yes, an Issue Review is required to be launched." value="Yes" onchange="setAutoInitiateIRRadio()"/>&nbsp;Yes</label>
           <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radIssueReviewRequired" name="radIssueReviewRequired" alt="Select if an Issue Review is required." title="No, an Issue Review is not required to be launched." value="No" onchange="setAutoInitiateIRRadio()"/>&nbsp;No</label>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 form-group" >
              <label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label" for="radAutoInitiateIR">Initiate Issue Review?:</label>
              <div class="radio-list">
               <span><label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radAutoInitiateIR" name="radAutoInitiateIR" alt="An Issue Review was recommended." title="An Issue Review was recommended." value="Yes" />&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span>
               <span><label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radAutoInitiateIR" name="radAutoInitiateIR" alt="An Issue Review was not recommended." title="An Issue Review was not recommended." value="No" />&nbsp;No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span>
              </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: *The system I am working in DOES NOT ALLOW for the names and ids to be different* <-- So the system you are working on requires invalid HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

Changing .attr to .prop fixed the issue.

Checked attribute is tied to defaultChecked property which means the element will only be checked for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for :

**Note :** Checking one radio button, automatically sets `checked` to `false` for other radio buttons in that radio group.

**One more thing :** You can use different id's and names for same input.

```js
var firstTime = true;
var firstYes = true;
var firstNo = true;

function setAutoInitiateIRRadio() {

  alert($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val());

  if (firstTime) {
    if ($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
      $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="Yes"]').attr('checked', true);
      firstYes = false;
    } else if ($('input[name="radIssueReviewRequired"]:checked').val() == "No") {
      $('input:radio[name="radAutoInitiateIR"][value="No"]').attr('checked', true);
      firstNo = false;
    }
    firstTime = (firstYes || firstNo);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
  <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label" for="radIssueReviewRequired">Issue Review Required?:</label>
  <div class="radio-list">
    <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radIssueReviewRequired" name="radIssueReviewRequired" alt="Select if an Issue Review is required." title="Yes, an Issue Review is required to be launched." value="Yes" onchange="setAutoInitiateIRRadio()"/>&nbsp;Yes</label>
    <label id="radIssueReviewRequired-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radIssueReviewRequired" name="radIssueReviewRequired" alt="Select if an Issue Review is required." title="No, an Issue Review is not required to be launched." value="No" onchange="setAutoInitiateIRRadio()"/>&nbsp;No</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
  <label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label" for="radAutoInitiateIR">Initiate Issue Review?:</label>
  <div class="radio-list">
    <span><label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radAutoInitiateIR" name="radAutoInitiateIR" alt="An Issue Review was recommended." title="An Issue Review was recommended." value="Yes" />&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span>
    <span><label id="radAutoInitiateIR-label"><input type="radio" class="mc-click" id="radAutoInitiateIR" name="radAutoInitiateIR" alt="An Issue Review was not recommended." title="An Issue Review was not recommended." value="No" />&nbsp;No&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></span>
  </div>
</div>
```